# igraph finding all subgraphs of specified shape

Tags: r, igraph

I'm interested in finding all "V" subgraphs in a graph, i.e. all triples of vertices that would become triangles if you add an extra edge. Is there an efficient way of doing this with R's version of igraph?

Comment: see ?triad.census. 021D, 021U, 021C, 111D, 111U, and 201 all satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @paqmo: Thanks! However, I'd like to enumerate all such vertex groups, as opposed to just counting the different types

Comment: See "subgraph isomorphisms": http://igraph.org/r/doc/subgraph_isomorphisms.html

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in the sna package; not sure if it is possible in igraph. In sna, the `triad.classify` will tell you the type of triad given any three vertices. To enumerate them all, you need to find all combinations of three vertices and pass this to `triad.classify`. Then, create a data frame where each row gives the triad and its classification. Then subset to the triads you care about. This will take a while if you have a lot of vertices! You can convert from igraph to network object using `intergraph`.

Here's an example using a random graph:

```
library(sna); library(igraph); library(intergraph)
g <- sample_gnp(25,0.25, directed = T)
g <- asNetwork(g)
triads <- combn(1:network.size(g),3, simplify = F)
triad_census <- lapply(1:length(triads), 
                       function(x) triad.classify(g,tri=triads[[x]]))
triads <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(triads), nrow=length(triads), byrow=T),
                     triad = unlist(triad_census))
triads <- triads[which(triads$triad == "021D" | 
                       triads$triad == "021U" | 
                       triads$triad == "021C" |
                       triads$triad == "111D" |
                       triads$triad == "111U" |
                       triads$triad == "201"),]

head(triads)
   X1 X2 X3 triad
3   1  2  5  021C
4   1  2  6  111U
6   1  2  8  021U
8   1  2 10  021C
10  1  2 12  021C
12  1  2 14  021U
```